# Cuál es la forma correcta de conectarme a una base de datos DB2 IBM desde Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, sql, jupyter, db2, ibm-watson

No puedo conectarme desde jupyter a DB2 ibm no se cual es el error...introducir la d[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]escripción de la imagen aquí

Comment: Poco se puede decir con lo que nos das. El error dice que sigas el formato de _sqlalchemy_, pero no vemos la cadena de conexión completa. Así mismo, nos falta el resto de código que te ha conducido hasta el error.

Comment: !pip install  sqlalchemy == 1.3.9
!pip install  ibm_db_sa
!pip install  ipython_sql
!pip install  ibm_db

Comment: esos fueron los comandos que escribi

Comment: Está bien saber qué módulos has instalado. Pero  yo veo una llamada a `%sql` que se corta, por lo que no puedo saber si estás usando correctamente el formato SQLAlchemy, que es el error que te da. Sería mejor que editaras la pregunta para completarla y, siempre que sea posible, pon todo el código como texto usando las facilidades del editor.